# git clone fails with Operation timed out after 0 milliseconds with 0 out of 0 bytes received

Tags: git

`git clone` fails with:

```bash
GIT_CURL_VERBOSE=1 git clone https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui.git
Cloning into 'swagger-ui'...
* Couldn't find host github.com in the .netrc file; using defaults
* Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
*   Trying 192.30.252.129...
* Connected to github.com (192.30.252.129) port 443 (#0)
* found 174 certificates in /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
* Operation timed out after 0 milliseconds with 0 out of 0 bytes received
* Closing connection 0
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui.git/': Operation timed out after 0 milliseconds with 0 out of 0 bytes received
```

I've tried `export GIT_SSL_NO_VERIFY=1` but still same issue.

I'm on **Ubuntu 14.04** and using **Git 1.9.1**

Comment: "found 174 certificates in /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt" you may have a problem with your ssh certificates. Try to clone it using other protocol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was the company proxy doin ssl inspection the github connection

Comment: how excactly did you fix this problem?

Comment: can you help on this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50358288/git-push-pull-clone-with-no-response