# git push, pull, clone with no response

Tags: linux, git

When I run `git push`, `pull`, `clone` none of them works.

I get following error when i'm trying to push or pull or clone a repository

> fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/myUsername/myRepo/':
>   Operation timed out after 0 milliseconds with 0 out of 0 bytes
>   received

What can cause such an issue? Where and what should I check to find out what is causing this problem?

Comment: Googling the error message itself shows that's not git-related but a message returned by the **libcurl** (confirmed when launching the `strings` command on it). Seems to be a common problem. People talk about issues with SSL versions or unverified hosts.

Answer (score 0):

You are cloning the wrong url. Git repo urls are in the form of:

```
https://github.com/username/repository.git
```

With that url you are trying to clone the repository public (or private, depending on your account) front page.

Answer (score 0):

It should be some thing like below:

```
git clone https://github.com/myUsername/myRepo.git
```

Answer (score 0):

According [this link](https://github.com/supercollider/supercollider/wiki/git-cheat-sheet#problems-with-submodule-state-update), When switching branches and doing a submodule update git sometimes messes up the submodule status without you having touched it.

So following codes fixes the issue

```
git submodule init
git submodule update
```