# Git can't clone public repository from docker container

Tags: git, docker, ssl, curl

I'm trying to build a docker image with the dockerfile which contains the following command.

```
RUN GIT_CURL_VERBOSE=1 git clone --depth=1 -b  master https://code.aliyun.com/SmileYang/adaptive-loadbalance.git
```

I get the error while building the docker image:

```
 ---> Running in 89727fcab44a
+ GIT_CURL_VERBOSE=1 git clone --depth=1 -b master https://code.aliyun.com/SmileYang/adaptive-loadbalance.git
Cloning into 'adaptive-loadbalance'...
* Couldn't find host code.aliyun.com in the .netrc file; using defaults
*   Trying 120.55.150.20...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to code.aliyun.com (120.55.150.20) port 443 (#0)
* found 151 certificates in /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
* found 604 certificates in /etc/ssl/certs
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* Operation timed out after 300014 milliseconds with 0 out of 0 bytes received
* Curl_http_done: called premature == 1
* stopped the pause stream!
* Closing connection 0
fatal: unable to access 'https://code.aliyun.com/SmileYang/adaptive-loadbalance.git/': Operation timed out after 300014 milliseconds with 0 out of 0 bytes received
```

I try to run the git clone command without docker, and i get the following output:

```
aijiaming@ubuntu:~$ GIT_CURL_VERBOSE=1 git clone --depth=1 -b master https://code.aliyun.com/SmileYang/adaptive-loadbalance.git
Cloning into 'adaptive-loadbalance'...
* Couldn't find host code.aliyun.com in the .netrc file; using defaults
*   Trying 120.55.150.20...
* Connected to code.aliyun.com (120.55.150.20) port 443 (#0)
* found 148 certificates in /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
* found 594 certificates in /etc/ssl/certs
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* SSL connection using TLS1.2 / ECDHE_RSA_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
*        server certificate verification OK
*        server certificate status verification SKIPPED
*        common name: code.aliyun.com (matched)
*        server certificate expiration date OK
*        server certificate activation date OK
*        certificate public key: RSA
*        certificate version: #3
*        subject: C=CN,ST=ZheJiang,L=HangZhou,O=Alibaba (China) Technology Co.\, Ltd.,CN=code.aliyun.com
*        start date: Wed, 09 Oct 2019 02:01:07 GMT
*        expire date: Fri, 09 Oct 2020 02:01:07 GMT
*        issuer: C=BE,O=GlobalSign nv-sa,CN=GlobalSign Organization Validation CA - SHA256 - G2
*        compression: NULL
* ALPN, server accepted to use http/1.1
> GET /SmileYang/adaptive-loadbalance.git/info/refs?service=git-upload-pack HTTP/1.1

------------------more output-------------------------
```

Here is a similar question:

[git clone fails with Operation timed out after 0 milliseconds with 0 out of 0 bytes received](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36084657/git-clone-fails-with-operation-timed-out-after-0-milliseconds-with-0-out-of-0-by)

I don't know why it stopped at `ALPN, offering http/1.1`, it seems that it's a **SSL** related problem.

git version is **2.11.0**

Comment: Try adding this to your Dockerfile before you clone: `RUN apk add  -update 
       ca-certificates 
    && update-ca-certificates`

Comment: Hmm try adding an entry to your hosts file, for example `C:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts`, `127.0.0.1 host.docker.internal`. Also try running a simple ping in a docker container to ensure you can connect to the internet from within a container. I am assuming you can clone the repo without being logged into git?

Comment: Really thanks for your reply @dustytrash , I got the following output, and it didn't work. `ca-certificates is already the newest version (20161130+nmu1+deb9u1). ca-certificates set to manually installed. Updating certificates in /etc/ssl/certs`

Comment: Thank you very much @dustytrash. I has run `ping code.aliyun.com` within the container before, and it could connect. There's no need to log into git because it's a public repository. Do you know what kind of problem make the connection stop at `ALPN, offering http/1.1`?

Comment: Seems like a problem with TLS. Are you using an Ubuntu container? Try using a windows container (just to see if it works). Could be a firewall issue. Are you using a proxy? If you post your dockerfile I could test to see if I get the same issue or not